# Multiple Animations For Same UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift4, cabasicanimation

I am trying to add multiple animations for my image view, but only one of them is animated. Please check the below code. I created scale and rotate animations for my image view but only i see the scale animation when run the below code.

```
//Rotate animation
let rotation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: 
"transform.rotation.y")
rotation.toValue = 0
rotation.fromValue = 2.61

//Scale animation
let scale: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
scale.toValue = 1
scale.fromValue = 0

//Adding animations to group
let group = CAAnimationGroup()
group.animations = [rotation,scale]
group.duration = 0.2

myImage.layer.add(group, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation occurs but the duration is less to notice

```
group.duration = 0.2
```

when changed to 5 seconds see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your completion you can put your animations, when finish one, wait second.. and etc

```
   let myImage = UIImageView()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        let rotation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: 
        "transform.rotation.y")
        rotation.toValue = 0
        rotation.fromValue = 2.61
    }, completion: { (value: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            //you can here put your other animation
        })
    })
```

Comment: You should consider using `animatingKeyFrames` to avoid all the nesting. Check out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-keyframe-animations-using-animatekeyframes